# Diagonal bishop moves on chess board with python

Tags: python, math, chess

I have the following problem

In chess, the bishop moves diagonally, any number of squares. Given two different squares of the chessboard, determine whether a bishop can go from the first to the second in one move.

The program receives as input four numbers from 1 to 8, specifying the column and row numbers of the starting square and the column and row numbers of the ending square. The program should output YES if a Bishop can go from the first square to the second in one move, or NO otherwise.

For example:

Input:
2
3
5
6

Output:

YES

It is assumed that the cells are numbered from left to right and from bottom to top, i.e., the bottom left cell has column number 1 and row number 1 while the bottom-right cell has column number 8 and row number 1.

**How far did I get?**

I have managed to get to check if the bishop moved diagonally, but it can move any diagonal, so it is not correct. Can someone give me some hints?

my code

```
initial_coord_x=int (input('enter the initial x'))
initial_coord_y=int (input('enter the initial y'))
final_coord_x=int (input('enter the final x'))
final_coord_y=int (input('enter the final y'))
if final_coord_x<=8 and final_coord_y<=8:
  if final_coord_x < initial_coord_x and final_coord_y > initial_coord_y:
    print ('you moved legally')
  elif final_coord_x < initial_coord_x and final_coord_y < initial_coord_y:
    print ('you moved legally')
  elif final_coord_x > initial_coord_x and final_coord_y > initial_coord_y:
    print ('you moved legally')
  elif final_coord_x > initial_coord_x and final_coord_y < initial_coord_y:
    print ('you moved legally')
  else:
    print ('no!')


else:
  print ('illegal move, you moved outside the chessboard')
```

Comment: What does "it can move any diagonal" mean?

Comment: Note that there are only two possible diagonal directions, and they have mathematical equations `y = x + k` and `y = -x + k`; every value of k leads to a distinct parallel diagonal. Two squares (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) which are on the same diagonal will satisfy the equation for the same value of `k`. Since the value of k can be obtained by rewriting the two possible equations as `k = y-x` and `k = y+x` respectively, the final conclusion is: (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are on the same diagonal if and only if x1+y1 = x2+y2 or x1-y1 = x2-y2.

Comment: See also this related question on https://chess.stackexchange.com : [How can one know where two diagonal lines meet?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37029/how-can-one-know-where-two-diagonal-lines-meet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the possibility of bishop moving (at existing cells) it is enough to check whether the absolute value of horizontal displacement is equal to the absolute value of vertical displacement (so both positions lie in the same diagonal)

```
dx = abs(final_coord_x - initial_coord_x)
dy = abs(final_coord_y - initial_coord_y)
if (dx == dy) and (dx > 0):
     legal move
```

Comment: The absolute value method is the best!